# Get filtered array size in AutoCompleteTextview

Tags: android, arraylist, filtering, android-adapter, autocompletetextview

I am working on the project in which user can search data. For that, I have implemented `AutoCompleteTextView`.

```
 autoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CheckRiskActivity.this,
                                        R.layout.auto_text_row, druglist));
                                autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
//druglist is my arraylist
```

Text change listener is as below:

```
autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // here I want to get the size of filtered array list every time when the user adds any character.
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Explanation: If my initial array size is 100 and if the user types 'a', then I want to get the size of filtered array.

**Note:** I have tried `autoComplete.getAdapter().getCount();` but it gives the actual result after adding one more character.

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074316/efficient-way-of-finding-all-strings-of-an-arraylist-which-contains-a-substring

Comment: it is a time taking process if I will go to find substring on each text change. So I causes delay in result.

Comment: make it efficient don't just request on everyString change give 1 second or 2 sec delay before you hit a req for filtered result

Comment: it is already implemented, but to avoid those 1 or 2 seconds I am finding an alternate solution.
If resultant arralist size is 0 then I just need to show 'No data found'. So for that, I need arraylist size on each text change.

Comment: @RonakThakkar, please, see my answer below and let me know if the solution is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get correct filtered items' count in `TextWatcher`, because filtering usually takes longer time than `TextWatcher` event listeners. Therefore you get incorrect `autoComplete.getAdapter().getCount()` in `afterTextChanged()`. I would recommend to use custom listener which will be called every time when filtered items are changed.

I will provide 2 similar approaches: using separate classes and using only 1 class.

**APPROACH 1**: 
Your adapter should look like:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{
    private List<String>    tempItems;
    private List<String>    suggestions;
    private FilterListeners filterListeners;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items)
    {
        super(context, resource, 0, items);

        tempItems = new ArrayList<>(items);
        suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setFilterListeners(FilterListeners filterFinishedListener)
    {
        filterListeners = filterFinishedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    Filter nameFilter = new Filter()
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
        {
            if (constraint != null)
            {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (String names : tempItems)
                {
                    if (names.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        suggestions.add(names);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            }
            else
            {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
        {
            List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;

            if (filterListeners != null && filterList!= null)
                filterListeners.filteringFinished(filterList.size());

            if (results != null && results.count > 0)
            {
                clear();
                for (String item : filterList)
                {
                    add(item);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

An interface which is used to inform you when filtering will be finished:

```
public interface FilterListeners
{
    void filteringFinished(int filteredItemsCount);
}
```

And you can use it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FilterListeners
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        autoComplete.setThreshold(1);

        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
        stringList.add("Black");
        stringList.add("White");
        stringList.add("Yellow");
        stringList.add("Blue");
        stringList.add("Brown");


        final AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
        adapter.setFilterListeners(this);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void filteringFinished(int filteredItemsCount)
    {
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", " filteringFinished  count = " + filteredItemsCount);
    }
}
```

**APPROACH 2**:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
    import android.widget.Filter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
            autoComplete.setThreshold(1);

            final List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
            stringList.add("Black");
            stringList.add("White");
            stringList.add("Yellow");
            stringList.add("Blue");
            stringList.add("Brown");

            final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList)
            {
                private List<String> tempItems   = stringList;
                private List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();

                @Override
                public Filter getFilter()
                {
                    return nameFilter;
                }

                Filter nameFilter = new Filter()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
                    {
                        if (constraint != null)
                        {
                            suggestions.clear();
                            for (String names : tempItems)
                            {
                                if (names.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                {
                                    suggestions.add(names);
                                }
                            }
                            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                            filterResults.values = suggestions;
                            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                            return filterResults;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new FilterResults();
                        }
                    }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
                {
                    List<String> filterList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                    filteringFinished(filterList.size());

                    if (results != null && results.count > 0)
                    {
                        clear();
                        for (String item : filterList)
                        {
                            add(item);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        };

        autoComplete.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    private void filteringFinished(int filteredItemsCount)
    {
        Log.i("LOG_TAG", " filteringFinished  count = " + filteredItemsCount);
    }
}
```

`filteringFinished()` method will be called when you enter something to an autocomplete input field and it gets filtered.

**UPDATE** (Trie Search):

I have created a Github project with a simple example of using [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) search algorithm to increase autocomplete performance very much.

https://github.com/saqada/android-AutoCompleteWithTrie

Comment: This is running perfectly, but it takes long time to display result. Is there any possible optimization?

Comment: In my case, I have used my posted answer, However, in general perspective(Demo) your answer is working like a charm so you very well deserves this bounty reputation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RonakThakkar, thank you. I think performance is pretty good, checked with 200 values. However, I will let you know if I can improve the code.

Comment: Actually, I am having more than 30K values. So I understand It might take some of the seconds.

Comment: I have also posted an answer, Is it a recommended way?

Comment: @RonakThakkar, a bit late but I just wanted to inform you that I improved the code by adding Trie search algorithm. It works now much faster with even more than 100k values.

Comment: you can use a timer to execute TimerTask with some small delay. see my answer.

Comment: @e.hadid,usage of a timer for such kind of tasks is not a good practice.

Comment: @AyazAlifov tell me why? and also see my update, what about the second solution?

Answer (score 4):

according to Ayaz Alifov answer you cannot get correct filtered items' count in `TextWatcher`, because filtering usually takes longer time than `TextWatcher` event listeners.

but i have done a trick with a `timerTask`. so the TextWatcher would execute after counting.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(
new TextWatcher() {
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    private Timer timer=new Timer();
    private final long DELAY = 1000; // milliseconds

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                      // adapter.getCount()  will give you the correct item's counts 
                      Log.d(TAG, "run: afterTextChanged " + adapter.getCount());
                }
            }, 
            DELAY
        );
    }
}
);
```

**Edited: 5/Sep/2019**

you can also get items count with the help of setting a `registerDataSetObserver`.

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + adapter.getCount());
    }
});
```

in this way the `onChanged()` will call every time text change. But if the suggestion list becomes empty, it will not be called.

Comment: autoeditText.postDelayed also worked to get adapter count.

Answer (score 1):

**Basically, we have to implement Filterable at Adapter class**

```
public class DrugListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
    Filterable {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
drugsFilter drugsFilter;

List<Drug> drugList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Drug> drugListOrig;

public DrugListAdapter(Context context,
        List<Drug> drugList) {
    super();

    this.context = context;
    this.drugList = drugList;
    this.drugListOrig = new ArrayList<>(
            drugList);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void resetData() {
    drugList = drugListOrig;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return drugList.size();
}

@Override
public Drug getItem(int position) {
    return drugList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView mVendorName;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Drug item = drugList.get(position);
    if (view == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_drug,
                parent, false);
        viewHolder.mVendorName = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.item_drug_drug_name);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    viewHolder.mVendorName.setText(item.getDrug_name());
    return view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (drugsFilter == null) {
        drugsFilter = new DrugsFilter();
    }
    return drugsFilter;
}

public class DrugsFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        // We implement here the filter logic
        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            // No filter implemented we return all the list
            results.values = drugListOrig;
            results.count = drugListOrig.size();
        } else {
            // We perform filtering operation
            List<Drug> sList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Drug p : drugList) {
                if (p.getDrug_name().toUpperCase()
                        .startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                    sList.add(p);
            }

            results.values = sList;
            results.count = sList.size();

        }
        return results;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        if (results.count == 0)
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        else {
            drugList = (List<Drug>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

}

This part is for `EditText`  and `TextWatcher`

```
    String m;
    mDrugEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {

            if (count < before) {
                adapter.resetData();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1) {
                mDrugEditText.invalidate();
            }
            if (s.length() == 3) {
                if (mDrugEditText
                        .isPerformingCompletion()) {
                    return;
                }
                adapter.resetData();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            m = s.toString();
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have gone through the basic search options available in android/java and you are not satisfied with the results.

If you do not want to go through entire list at every text change, the only way is to implement a datastructure which does that.

The obvious solution will be trie.[read this to get an idea about  trie](https://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure)

Now, this works on the concept of pre-processing the data before searching. Since you have limited elements - it will not take much time, and you can possibly do it when the page loads.

Steps - 
- Process and index all elements on load. Put indexes on a k-ary tree (it will be 32-ary, every character will be an alphabet). 
- on text changed - traverse to the node and get the count. It will take O(1).

I believe this is the fastest you can go.

The above will work best if you have words indexed or if you just have to do startswith.

Answer (score 0):

Sa Qada's answer is a very good approach, However, my below answer gave me better performance in my case.

```
autoCompleteTextViewCheckRisk.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (CheckRiskActivity.this, R.layout.auto_text_row, druglist));
//druglist is the Arraylist of String.
autoCompleteTextViewCheckRisk.setThreshold(1);
```

**Text Change Listener:**

```
autoCompleteTextViewCheckRisk.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filter(druglist, s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {

        }
    });
```

**Method for Filter:**

```
private void filter(ArrayList<String> originalArrayList, String query) {

    query = query.toLowerCase();
    filteredArrayList.clear();
    //filtered arraylist is also Arraylist of String, Just declared as global
    for (String itemName : originalArrayList) {
        final String text = itemName.toLowerCase();
        if (text.startsWith(query)) {
            filteredArrayList.add(itemName);
        }
    }

    if (filteredArrayList.size() == 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "filter: No data found");
    }
}
```