# Count of total suggestions as per input data on autocompletetextview - android

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

How can I get **total number** of suggestions that is exactly matching the input data on autocompletetextview

```
 placeView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Places item = (Places) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    if(!place_id.equals("")) {
                        place_name = item.getPlaceName();
                        place_id = item.getOnlineId();
                        place_panchayat_id = item.getPanchayat_name();
                    } else {
                        placeView.setText("");
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: `Adapter#getCount()`

Comment: @pskink You mean adapterName.getCount() ?

Comment: i mean [Adapter#getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount())

Comment: @pskink It will return total number of items present in that adapter but what I want is when i enter 1 or 2 characters in the autocompletetextview it will show some suggestion, which are exactly matching to the input I need this suggested items count.

Comment: `getCount` will return the suggested items count

Comment: This might help you for you question : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640188/10775846](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44640188/10775846)

Comment: @LazyTeddy Thank You... Usage of custom adapter may work in the scenario...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
placeView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //getCount() Method give the count from the adapter;
                int count = parent.getCount();
                Places item = (Places) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(!place_id.equals("")) {
                    place_name = item.getPlaceName();
                    place_id = item.getOnlineId();
                    place_panchayat_id = item.getPanchayat_name();
                } else {
                    placeView.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: parent.getCount() will gives total number of items present in the adapter. but I need total  number of suggested items those will come after typing some input in the autocompletetextview